# Find the equations of the tangents drawn to the curve $y^2-2x^3-4y+8=0$ from the point $(1,2)$

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

Find the equations of the tangents drawn to the curve $y^2-2x^3-4y+8=0$ from the point $(1,2)$

---

$$2x^3=y^2-4y+8$$

If $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point on the curve $$2x_1^3=y_1^2-4y_1+8\ \ \ \ (1)$$

The equation of the tangent at $(x_1,y_1)$
$$\dfrac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}=\dfrac{6x_1^2}{2y_1-4}$$

Now as it has to pass through $(1,2)$

$$\dfrac{2-y_1}{1-x_1}=\dfrac{6x_1^2}{2y_1-4}\ \ \ \ (2)$$
I am stuck here.The tangents given in the answer are $2\sqrt3x-y=2(\sqrt3-1)$ and $2\sqrt3x+y=2(\sqrt3+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point it's basically solving a system of two nonlinear equations in two variables.  The equations are what you labeled $(1)$ and $(2)$.

From $(2)$ we can remove a factor of $2$ on the right and clear denominators to get: $$-y_1^2 + 4y_1 - 4 = 3x_1^2 - 3x_1^3$$
And we want to solve this simultaneously with: $$2x_1^3 = y_1^2 - 4y_1 + 8$$
In the first equation above, let's rewrite the LHS as $$-y_1^2 + 4y_1 - 4 = -(y_1^2 - 4y_1 + 8) + 4 = -2x_1^3 + 4.$$
Now solve that first equation above for $x_1$, using $-2x_1^3 + 4$ as the new LHS.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve for $(x_1, y_1)$ using the combination of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$.  I'm not sure how you got Equation $(2)$ from the previous equation, since they are not the same.